# Finding the range of a matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Consider the linear transformation define by

$$u(x) = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 - \bar{x} \\
x_2 - \bar{x} \\ 
\vdots \\
x_m - \bar{x}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
for all $x \in R^m$, where $\bar{x} = (1/m) \sum x_i$.

Find the matrix $A$ for which $u(x) = Ax$, and then determine the dimension of the range and null spaces of $A$.

I found $A$ to be:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
(1-\frac{1}{m}) - \frac{1}{m} \cdots -\frac{1}{m}\\
-\frac{1}{m} + (1-\frac{1}{m}) \cdots - \frac{1}{m}\\
-\frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{m} + (1-\frac{1}{m})
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_m
\end{bmatrix}
=
I_m -\frac{1}{m}1_m 1'_m
$$

I am stuck at how to find the dimension of the range because the book has the answer has $\dim(R) = m-1$ but I'm not seeing where they get that from matrix $A$.

Comment: It is easier to find the dimension of the nullspace first and then use the rank-nullity theorem to figure out the dimension of the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The easiest approach is to start by finding the nullspace, which is the space of solutions to the equation $u(x) = 0$. From there, the rank-nullity theorem says that we have
$$
\dim(\mathcal R(u)) = n - \dim(\mathcal N(u)).
$$

Comment: ok thank you, i'll look into that theorem and see if I can get the solution. The other thing I saw is that if the sum of each row vector is zero then the rank of the matrix is at most min(m,m) - 1 = m - 1

Comment: @AllenRahrooh Right; that's exactly what you get from the rank-nullity theorem. The sum of each row-vector being zero tells you that the nullspace is at least one dimensional.

Comment: I see now thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\tr}{\mathrm{tr}}$
If you are just looking for the rank of $A$, here is a (less direct) way. Since it is easy to verify that $A$ is idempotent, by applying the property of idempotent matrix (its rank is identical to its trace), we claim that:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{rank}(A) = \tr(A) = \tr(I_{(m)} - m^{-1}1_m1_m') = 
\tr(I_{(m)}) - m^{-1}\tr(1_m1_m') = m - m^{-1}\tr(1_m'1_m) = m - 1,
\end{align*}
which is the dimension of the linear operator $A$.

Comment: I see thank you. Interesting to see different ways to solve the problem